# Is it possible to remove or at least hide the “Family Sharing” Preference Pane from Catalina?

Tags: macos, mac, catalina, system-settings, preferences

I can hide the other preference panes the usual way (Preferences -> Menubar -> View -> Customize) but not this one. Is it possible at all?

Comment: Can you specify what is it that you want to achieve by hiding the preference pane?

Comment: I'd like to not see it.

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered that if you log out of your iCloud account, the Family Sharing pref.pane goes away. It's a very flawed solution, but it does work for me.